# Line integral of a scalar field

Tags: integration, line-integrals

Given the following curve
$$\alpha(t)=(t-\sin(t),1-\cos(t)),\quad 0\leq t\leq\pi$$
I have to evaluate
$$\oint_{\alpha}xy\,ds$$
Since
$$\alpha'(t)=(1-\cos(t),\sin(t))$$
then
$$\|\alpha'(t)\|=\sqrt{2-2\cos(t)}=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-\cos(t)}$$
So
$$\oint_{\alpha}xy\,ds=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{2}(t-\sin(t))(1-\cos(t))^{3/2}\,dt$$
I thought that, if $u=t-\sin(t)\Rightarrow du=(1-\cos(t))dt$, but I don't know how to proceed with $3/2$ in the exponent.

Comment: That indefinite integral is $$-\frac{1}{90} \sqrt{1-\cos (t)} \csc \left(\frac{t}{2}\right) \left(9 \sin \left(\frac{5
   t}{2}\right)+270 t \cos \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)-5 \left(90 \sin
   \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)+5 \sin \left(\frac{3 t}{2}\right)+6 t \cos \left(\frac{3
   t}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: Wow... is there any easier method to evaluate it? I mean, not necessarily the integral itself, but my problem.

Comment: I would note that $\sqrt {2-2\cos t} = 2\sin \frac {t}{2}$ then using the substitution $2u=t$ you should have a fairly straightforward integral to evaluate.